# setting google drive file access permission to "anyone with the link to access" gives 403. how to solve?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

Making the API request
[image: making the api request]

403 response
[image: 403 response]

I want to set permissions to my google drive file programmatically as if anyone has the google drive sharable link so he can read. After setting the `role` as `reader` and `type` as `anyone` trying the api gives me `403`. any help would be appreciated. Please refer the images above.

here is a part of my HTTP GET response

```
    "userPermission":{  
      "kind":"drive#permission",
      "etag":"\"v8V6DvTBE_bfiGlEO9jLLdDEcEE/vrb4MS7MSuazJcKlWO78yMuKxF0\"",
      "id":"me",
      "selfLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1Vnp6v2VSE3sHKb9H9ChJPc8VPozuVtyd/permissions/me",
      "role":"owner",
      "type":"user"
   },
   "originalFilename":"1200px-Arriva_T6_nearside.JPG",
   "fileExtension":"JPG",
   "md5Checksum":"52f04535ea275c8be7ad87853a49fb87",
   "fileSize":"343589",
   "quotaBytesUsed":"343589",
   "ownerNames":[  
      "Dev Drive"
   ],
   "owners":[  
      {  
         "kind":"drive#user",
         "displayName":"Dev Drive",
         "isAuthenticatedUser":true,
         "permissionId":"00918695921514386946",
         "emailAddress":"devdrive@finetechlk.net"
      }
   ],
```

Comment: what link are you giving them?

Comment: Do you have sufficient permissions to edit that file? It's not 503 error, it's 403 forbidden.

Comment: @DaImTo not clear what you are asking. im not giving them any link. im giving them the file id, type and role

Comment: **anyone with the link to access**  what link?  you can&#39;t just give someone a file id they need permission.  File ids can change depending upon how you upload any changes

Comment: @DaImTo i'm talking about the google drive sharable link. thanks for pointing that out. editing my question.

Comment: @DaImTo I'm talking about giving the read only access to anyone so that file link becomes a public link. Thats all i need to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientFilePermissions",
    "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."
 }
}
```

Means just that The current authenticated user does not have permissions to the file.  A user can not preform an action on a file they do not have permissions on.

I suggest that you do a [File.get](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/drive.files.get?fields=*&_h=5&) on the file Id you are working with and see what permissions the current authenticated user has to that file.  You will also be able to see the owner of the file.

Note the file i am testing with was shared with me by another user.   I dont have ownership of it and there for can not create permissions on it.

```
  {
   "kind": "drive#user",
   "displayName": "xxx",
   "photoLink": "xxx",
   "me": false,
   "permissionId": "x642264676680223635",
   "emailAddress": "xxxxx@gmail.com"
  }
```

Setting a file to public does not create a public read link.  Depending upon the file type it may contain a webViewLink but this is not true of all file types.

**Solution**

How to solve your 403. Find the user who owns the file with the ID you are using and have them insert the permissions.  Or insert permissions on a file that the current user owns.

Comment: I tried the HTTP GET using file id. Also the response shows that the file file owner is me. I myself created this file yet google api doesn't allow me to change permissions of the file. I'll try to add a part of my response into my question

Comment: When you authecate the try me make sure you are doing it with this gmail account then.  The try me says you do not own the file and there for can not change the permissions.    You could also do it with your own code try me is just ment for testing not for acutal use.